# Screen goes black, at random times. *ERROR* atombios stuck executing C88E

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

Well, I noticed a pattern but it tells me nothing.
First started happening while I was on Linux Mint 18.2
After a while, I installed Antergos where it continued.
It happens mostly immediately after grub loads.
To remedy the situation I have to reboot multiple times until the boot goes through. Seldom the screen goes off after booting fully.
Rarely while I am watching a video or playing OA.
In the system log I consistently find this report:

[[drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting](https://pastebin.com/Hvygp3FJ)

I tried searching this error on the web, most of the things I found was pretty old solved ubuntu bugs to do with intel graphics working at the same time as the amd, which is also what i have, amd being:

```
[raa@raa ~]$ lspci | grep -i VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood XT [Radeon HD 5670/5690/5730]
```

The thing is my intel is disabled.

```
[raa@raa ~]$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood XT [Radeon HD 5670/5690/5730] [1002:68d8] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Please help me solve(or at least determine) this annoying issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that Linux has a hard time with some of the AMD graphics cards. For Mint/Debian systems, add 'nomodeset' to grub (kernel boot parameters). This works for many users with AMD/ATI-vga.
Since I had made the edit from a bootup system, I changed the `/etc/default/grub` through the terminal where you just change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet spalsh"` through nano editor. The difference between arch and debian is that where updating debian grub you use the command `sudo update-grub` on arch you have to `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and that's it. For more information visit https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting